# XNA Games running on Windows 8

Tags: xna, windows, windows-8

Will Games developed on XNA work under a Windows 8 environment?

I know the XNA project was killed off, and you can't develop it on Windows 8 (apparently), but will they still work under windows 8? I don't care about metro integration or whatever, even if they run in desktop mode that's fine.

I've been looking around and finding a bunch of contradictory answers - so maybe I can get a clear one from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the applications you write for XNA will still run on the desktop mode but not metro mode. If you care about Metro integration, check out [MonoGame](https://www.monogame.net). I develop normal XNA and MonoGame applications on Windows 8 and run them here as well; I can assure you they both function perfect on desktop mode.

Comment: Have you had any luck getting custom shaders working with MonoGame?

Comment: @RobCurr I have - but it's probably a bit off-topic for this particular answer. ;)

Comment: Oh good, thanks. I was considering porting the game over (it uses simple sprites) to Monogame. Is it worth it? And how difficult would it be?

Comment: Incredibly simple - it doesn't take much effort at all. :)